# How to use nested namespace in different files?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
//file.h

namespace first
{
  namespace second
  {
     void foo();
  }
}

//file.c
using namespace first::second;

void foo()
{
 ...
}

//main.c
using namespace first::second;
int main()
{
  foo();
}
```

the code above doesn't work as the compiler didn't recognize the foo(). where is my mistake?

Comment: What compiler do you have? (You may want to try using .h(pp)/.cpp as the extension for source files instead)

Comment: What about include directives?

Comment: You mind adding the actual error message to your question too? (Please don't add it as a comment!)

Comment: `using namespace` will affect function calls, but not definitions.  Your definition of `foo` is in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

This puts the implementation into the namespace

```
//file.c
namespace first
{
  namespace second
  {
   void foo()
   {
 ...
    }
  }
}
```

This tells main explicitly where to find foo:

```
//main.c
int main()
{
  ::first::second::foo();
}
```

Comment: I made the change on the file.c according to your answer, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you got an unresolved linking error when you tried to call `foo` from main in the example you posted. There are couple issues at play here starting from the top:

- file.h declares a `foo` existing in namespace `first::second`.
- file.c brings namespace `first::second` into filescope lookup but it *does not* affect function definitions. Thus the implementation of `void foo() {}` is actually a function defined in global scope -- not in `first::second` as you might expect.
- main.c brings namespace `first::second` into its filescope. The compiler will consider `first::second` as well as global scope `::` when you call foo in main. The compiler chooses `first::second::foo` since `file.h` doesn't declare the global `foo()`.
- you get a linking error for unresolved symbol because `first::second::foo` was never implemented.

In addition to Jay's suggestion, the other fix you can do is to fully qualify foo's definition similar to member functions:

```
// file.c
#include "file.h"

void first::second::foo()
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: WELL EXPLAINED! THANKS!